# Metric on Cartesian Product

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I'm currently stuck on an exercise where I need to show that if $(M,d)$ and $(N,\rho)$ are metric spaces, then $d_2((a,x),(b,y)) := \sqrt{d(a,b)^2 + \rho(x,y)^2}$ defines a metric on $M\times N$. I've already shown that the basic criteria of a metric are met, but I still need to show that the triangle ineqaulity holds.

I've tried using the triangle inequality on $d$ and $\rho$ and estimating the square root with $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\leq a+b$, but regardless of which order I've used them in, I seem to overestimate my target. I thought maybe I somehow need to use Cauchy-Schwarz, but I don't know how.

Comment: Your statement of the  problem is wrong. If $(a,b)\in M\times N$ then $a \in M$ and $b\in N$ so $d(a,b)$ may fail to exist. What it should say is $d_2((m,n), (m',n'))=$ $(d(m,m')^2+\rho(n,n')^2)^{1/2}$ when $m,m'\in M$ and $n,n'\in N.$ .... Write out the full statement of the triangle inequality to be proved. Invent some abbreviations for the terms for the $d$- and $rho$- distances. What you get is: RTP that if $p,q,r,s,t,u\geq 0$ with $p+q\geq r$ and $s+t\geq u$ then $(p^2+s^2)^{1/2}+(q^2+t^2)^{1/2}\geq$ $ (r^2+u^2)^{1/2}$.... (continued)...

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I edited it, that was a typo on my part. What do you mean with "RTP"? Clearly the last thing you wrote is what they ask to proof, so that doesn't really help me.

Comment: ...(Continued from previous  comment). Since the largest possible value of the RHS of that inequality is $((p+q)^2+(r+s)^2)^{1/2}.$ It suffices to show that $(p^2+s^2)^{1/2}+(q^2+t^2)^{1/2}\geq$ $ ((p+q)^2+(s+t)^2)^{1/2}$ for all non-negative real $p,q,s,t.$

Comment: RTP means Required To Prove. Often in the sense that " We have shown that if we can prove the following, then we are done."

Comment: In your second comment you wrote $(r+s)^2$ instead of $(s+t)^2$ as biggest possible. I don't think that's correct as you seem to change it in the next line.

Comment: Prior to your edit I could not tell whether or not you understood the Q.

Comment: Yes there is a typo in my second comment . And I only get 5 minutes to edit a comment and it's too late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(a,b,c) \in M$ and $(x,y,z) \in N$. You want to prove that
$$\sqrt{d(a,c)^2 + \rho(x,z)^2} \leq \sqrt{d(a,b)^2 + \rho(x,z)^2} + \sqrt{d(b,c)^2 + \rho(y,z)^2}$$

You have, by triangle inequality for $d$ and $\rho$ :
$$d(a,c)^2 + \rho(x,z)^2 \leq d(a,b)^2 + d(b,c)^2 + 2 d(a,b)d(b,c) + \rho(x,y)^2 + \rho(y,z)^2 + 2 \rho(x,y)\rho(y,z) \quad (1)$$

But on the other hand, you know that
$$(\rho(x,z)d(b,c) - \rho(y,z)d(a,b))^2 \geq 0$$
so
$$\rho(x,z)^2 d(b,c)^2 + \rho(y,z)^2d(a,b)^2 \geq 2 \rho(x,z)d(b,c)\rho(y,z)d(a,b)$$
Adding $d(a,b)^2d(b,c)^2 + \rho(x,y)^2 \rho(y,z)^2$ to this relation, you get
$$d(a,b)^2d(b,c)^2 + \rho(x,y)^2 \rho(y,z)^2 +\rho(x,z)^2 d(b,c)^2 + \rho(y,z)^2d(a,b)^2 \geq d(a,b)^2d(b,c)^2 + \rho(x,y)^2 \rho(y,z)^2 + 2 \rho(x,z)d(b,c)\rho(y,z)d(a,b)$$
i.e.
$$(d(a,b)^2 + \rho(x,z)^2)(d(b,c)^2 + \rho(y,z)^2) \geq (d(a,b)d(c,d)+\rho(x,y)\rho(y,z))^2$$
so
$$2 \sqrt{(d(a,b)^2 + \rho(x,z)^2)(d(b,c)^2 + \rho(y,z)^2)} \geq 2(d(a,b)d(c,d)+\rho(x,y)\rho(y,z)) $$
Injecting this in the equation $(1)$, you get
$$d(a,c)^2 + \rho(x,z)^2 \leq d(a,b)^2 + d(b,c)^2 + \rho(x,y)^2 + \rho(y,z)^2 + 2\sqrt{(d(a,b)^2 + \rho(x,z)^2)(d(b,c)^2 + \rho(y,z)^2)}$$
which is equivalent to
$$d(a,c)^2 + \rho(x,z)^2 \leq \left(\sqrt{d(a,b)^2+\rho(x,z)^2}+\sqrt{d(b,c)^2 + \rho(y,z)^2}\right)^2$$
i.e. 
$$\sqrt{d(a,c)^2 + \rho(x,z)^2} \leq \sqrt{d(a,b)^2 + \rho(x,z)^2} + \sqrt{d(b,c)^2 + \rho(y,z)^2}$$

Comment: It seems so easy now, but how did you come to this solution if I may ask? Working backwards it is hard to see how to estimate $2\sqrt{(d(a,b)^2 + \rho(x,z)^2)(d(b,c)^2 + \rho(y,z)^2)}$ and working forwards it's not trivial to see how to get anywhere either.

Comment: You can always transform the equation you want to prove into an equivalent equation. Here, you can "simplify" the relation you have to prove by taking the squares, and deleting the terms that are both on the left and on the right. Then you get another relation to prove. And you can do the same... until you arrive to a trivial equation ! And after that, you can rewrite all you did in the "normal" order.

Answer (score 0):

Let $m,m',m''\in M$ and $n,n',n''\in N .$ Let $p=d(m,m'), q=d(m',m''),r=d(m,m'').$ Let $s=\rho(n,n'), t=\rho (n',n''), u=\rho (n,n'').$

Let $A= (p^2+s^2)^{1/2}$ and $B=(q^2+t^2)^{1/2}.$ We wish to prove that $A+B\geq (r^2+u^2)^{1/2}.$

Let $C= ((p+q)^2+(s+t)^2)^{1/2}.$ Since $d$ and  $\rho$ are metrics, we have $p+q\geq r\ge 0$ and $s+t\geq u\ge 0,$ so $C\ge (r^2+u^2)^{1/2}.$ So it suffices to prove that $A+B\geq C.$

Since $A,B,C \geq  0$ we have $$ A+B\geq C \iff (A+B)^2\geq C^2 \iff$$ $$\iff p^2+s^2+q^2+t^2+2 ((p^2+s^2)(q^2+t^2))^{1/2}\geq p^2+q^2+s^2+t^2+2pq+2st$$ $$\iff ((p^2+s^2)(q^2+t^2))^{1/2}\geq pq+st \iff$$ $$\iff (p^2+s^2)(q^2+t^2)\geq (pq+st)^2\iff$$ $$\iff (pt-qs)^2\geq 0.$$

In the last two lines above, we have used the identity $(p^2+s^2)(q^2+t^2)=(pq+st)^2+(pt-qs)^2.$

Comment: Showing that $A+B\geq C$ is the same thing as answering the Q in the special  case $M=N=\Bbb R$ and $d(x,y)=\rho (x,y)=|x-y|.   $ That is, the Q reduces to this special case.

Comment: A geometric interpretation of $(p^2+s^2)(q^2+t^2)=(pq+st)^2+(pt-qs)^2$ is that if $D=(p,s), E=(q,t),$ and $O=(0,0)$ are points in $\Bbb R^2 $and $\angle DOE=\theta ,$ then $(p^2+s^2)(q^2+t^2)=|DO|^2\cdot |EO|^2$ and $(pq+st)^2=|DO|^2\cdot |EO|^2\cos^2\theta$ and $(pt-qs)^2=|DO|^2\cdot |EO|^2\sin^2\theta.$

Answer (score 0):

I saw this question on Page 18, Exercise 38 of the following reference

C. C. Pugh, Real Mathematical Analysis, 2nd Edition, Springer, 2015.

There is a hint at the end of this exercise in the book that says, use the **Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality**. To recall this, in an abstract inner product vector space $V$ over the Real field $\mathbb{R}$, we have

$$\left|\langle x,y\rangle\right|\leq\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}\sqrt{\langle y,y\rangle}.$$

If $V=\mathbb{R}^n$, $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, $y=(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ and $\langle x,y\rangle:=\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i$ then this inequality turns out to be

$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i\right|\leq\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2}.$$

Keep this in mind! Let your cartesian product to be $M=X\times Y$ with $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ being metric spaces. Introduce $p_1=(x_1,y_1),\,p_2=(x_2,y_2),\,p_3=(x_3,y_3)\in M$ and by definition we have 
$$d_M(p_1,p_2)=\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2}.$$
We want to show that $d_M$ is indeed a metric. Positive definiteness and symmetry are immidiate and easy to prove. The triangle inequality for $d_M$ reads as follows

\begin{align*}
d_M(p_1,p_3)&\leq d_M(p_1,p_2)+d_M(p_2,p_3), \\
\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_3)^2}&\leq \sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2} + \sqrt{d_X(x_2,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_2,y_3)^2}.
\end{align*}

To show that this is indeed true, we start with what we know about the metrics $d_X$ and $d_Y$

\begin{align*}
d_X(x_1,x_3)\leq d_X(x_1,x_2)+d_X(x_2,x_3), \qquad
d_Y(y_1,y_3)\leq d_Y(y_1,y_2)+d_Y(y_2,y_3).
\end{align*}

Taking square and then adding the result leaves us with

\begin{align*}
&d_X(x_1,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_3)^2\leq \\ 
&d_X(x_1,x_2)^2+d_X(x_2,x_3)^2+2d_X(x_1,x_2)d_X(x_2,x_3)+ \\
&d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2+d_Y(y_2,y_3)^2+2d_Y(y_1,y_2)d_Y(y_2,y_3), \\
\\
&d_X(x_1,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_3)^2\leq \\ 
&\big(d_X(x_1,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2\big)+\big(d_X(x_2,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_2,y_3)^2\big)+ \\
&2\big(d_X(x_1,x_2)d_X(x_2,x_3)+d_Y(y_1,y_2)d_Y(y_2,y_3)\big), \\
\end{align*}

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality for $n=2$, we observe that

\begin{align*}
&d_X(x_1,x_2)d_X(x_2,x_3)+d_Y(y_1,y_2)d_Y(y_2,y_3)\leq \\ &\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2}\sqrt{d_X(x_2,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_2,y_3)^2}
\end{align*}

Combining the last two results gives us

\begin{align*}
&d_X(x_1,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_3)^2\leq \\ 
&\Big(\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2}\Big)^2+\Big(\sqrt{d_X(x_2,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_2,y_3)^2}\Big)^2+ \\
&2\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2}\sqrt{d_X(x_2,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_2,y_3)^2}, \\
\\
&d_X(x_1,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_3)^2\leq \\ 
&\Big(\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2}+\sqrt{d_X(x_2,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_2,y_3)^2}\Big)^2, \\
\\
&\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_3)^2}\leq \\ 
&\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2}+\sqrt{d_X(x_2,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_2,y_3)^2}.
\end{align*}

This completes the proof. You can use the same way to prove for the Cartesian product of $n$ metric spaces $M=X_1\times\dots \times X_n$. For this purpose, you can use mathematical induction or a direct approach by employing Cauchy-Schwarz for an arbitrary $n$.